# How to store and retrieve image in java?

Tags: java, sql-server, servlets

I want to store image (upload) in database and retrieve it to jsp page. i am using JAVA and SQL SERVER 2012.

My table is imgtbl(name nvarchar(500),photo image)

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

see this [link](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/save_image.shtml) for how to save an image to a DB.  I am not sure that nvarchar is correct and I would rather go for a blob or similar.

Relevant code from link

```
("insert into save_image(name, city, image, Phone) "+ "values(?,?,?,?)");
psmnt.setString(1,"mahendra");
psmnt.setString(2,"Delhi");
psmnt.setString(4,"123456");
fis = new FileInputStream(image);
psmnt.setBinaryStream(3, (InputStream)fis, (int)(image.length()));
```

see also http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378813.aspx for a Microsoft bent on things.

Comment: nvarchar is for name
image for photo

And there is no any datatype like blob in sql server 2012 @Java1

Comment: How about VARBINARY(MAX):

Comment: see also http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378813.aspx for a Microsoft bent on things.

Comment: ok will try varbinary(max)

Comment: its not working... :(
can you give me demo?

Comment: see my answer, I believe it has a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the image to bytes and save in database as blob.